# mysql where clause resitriction?

Tags: php, mysql

I use below php code to generate a random id number

```
md5(uniqid(rand(), true)
```

the type of string it generate is something like this

```
9a423553ce53c4d7a6199fa9254bfdc5
```

I use that as an ID in Mysql table then I do a standard select query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 9a423553ce53c4d7a6199fa9254bfdc5
```

I get this error

```
Unknown column '9a423553ce53c4d7a6199fa9254bfdc5' in 'where clause'
```

if I just change the id to a simple number like `1` it works.

Why is this?

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating that in quotes? In your query `id = 9a423553ce53c4d7a6199fa9254bfdc5` You can compare two columns like `id = other_id` .. MySQL needs to know how to handle your query.

Comment: add quotes to the id

Comment: @Blake omg yep it worked.... post as an answer I will accept it. totally didnt not see that. I thought the weird string had some meaning in Mysql.

Comment: @codenoob Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried encapsulating that in quotes? In your query `id = 9a423553ce53c4d7a6199fa9254bfdc5` You can compare two columns like `id = other_id` .. MySQL needs to know how to handle your query.

For clarification, should be: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '9a423553ce53c4d7a6199fa9254bfdc5';`